# Show that if $E$ is a non-empty connected subset of a space $X$ which is both open and closed, then $E$ is a component.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that if $E$ is a non-empty connected subset of a space $X$ which is both open and closed, then $E$ is a component.

In order to show that $E$ is a component since it's connected it suffices to show that $E$ is maximal. That is if $C$ is a connected set such that $E \subset C \subset X$, then $C = E$ or $C = X$.

I have hard time showing that other one of the equalities $C = E$ or $C = X$ will be true. I don't think I have any data to work with. If $c \in C$, then if I could show that $c \in E$, then $C = E$ and equivalently if $x \in X$ and I could show that $x \in C$, then $C = X$, but this is not an approach I can take as I need to satisfy this *or* condition.

I only know that $E$ is clopen and I should be able to derive that it's component just from that, but it only gives me that $E^c$ is also clopen.

Do I need to use some property of components here that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about showing:

> If $C$ is connected with $E\subseteq C\subseteq X$, then $C=E$ or $C=X$

Since if $C=X$ is even possible, i.e. $X$ is connected, then $X$ is the one and only component so this is an ignorable statement. In other areas of mathematics, maximality (e.g., of a maximal ideal) means we should check the analogue of $C=E$ or $C=X$, but not so for connectivity. Again, if $C=X$ is possible, and $E$ is a component, then $C=E=X$, so it still suffices to check only that $C=E$.

$E$ is connected, so it is contained in a component $C$ with $C$ being connected. However, as $E$ is clopen in $X$, $E$ is clopen in $C$; as $C$ is connected and $E$ is nonempty, it follows that $C=E$. Done!

Warning: It is not generally true that connected components are clopen, and the connectivity hypothesis on $E$ cannot be dropped.

Comment: It seems that you're concluding that $C = E$ just from the fact that $E$ is clopen in $C$. How does this imply the equality? @FShrike

Comment: @SleepWalker By one (equivalent) definition of connectivity, $C$ is connected iff. "$A\subseteq C$ is clopen (in the subspace $C$) iff. $A=\emptyset$ or $A=C$". We apply this with $A=E$.

Comment: If you're used to, "$C$ is connected iff. $C=A\sqcup B$ as a disjoint union where $A$ and $B$ are both open in $C$ means either $A=C$ or $B=C$" then it's a good exercise to show that these definitions of connectivity are the same

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about this result. @FShrike

Answer (score 1):

$C=E \cup (C\setminus E)$. Note that $E=C\cap E$ is an open subset of $C$. Also, $C\setminus E=C\cap (X\setminus E)$ is an open subset of $C$. This contradicts connectedness of $C$ unless either $E$ or $C\setminus E$ is empty. Since the first one is non-empty we get $C=E$.